# clear error provider message when user input change to valid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Inside form I have txtbox with following event code

```
 private void txtCode_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
      char ch = e.KeyChar;
      if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
      {
          e.Handled = true;
          errorProvider1.SetError(txtCode, "numbers only");
      }
 }
```

Error icon is shown right to the txtbox with error message, how can I remove this error icon when user input is cleared or deleted or replaced with valid (digit) input?

These way it stays shown always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add else statement like

```
else
{
   errorProvider1.SetError(txtCode, "");
}
```